# dataTable - Reload table after form submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datatables

I already read a lot here but I can´t find a working solution! I have a datatable and inside one column there is an edit button. If a user clicks on the edit button a modal appears and user can change an entry from a datatable. Once the form is submitted, the changes are done inside the database.

Now I would like to automatically refresh my table withour doing a page reload. How can I achieve that? What do I have to call inside my success message?

Here is my code:

index.php:

```
if ($savetodo=="true") {
    $content=array("descr"=>$descr);
    updateToDoInfo($id,$content);

}
```

AJAX submit:

```
                <script>
                    $(function() {
                        $('#form_edittodo').on(\"submit\", function(event) {
                            event.preventDefault();

                            $.ajax({
                                url: 'index.php',
                                type: 'post',
                                data: $(this).serialize(),
                                beforeSend: function(){
                                        $('#loading').show();
                                    },
                                    complete: function(){
                                        $('#loading').hide();
                                    },
                                success: function() {
                                   // What should I enter here?
                            });
                        });
                    });
                </script>
```

datatable:

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#todolist12').DataTable();
    } );
    </script>
```

Would be great if someone can help me out.

Comment: Do you mean that you are using the jquery dataTables plugin when you're talking about "datatable"?

Comment: yes exactly! sorry forgot to mention that!

Comment: Just redraw your datatable in your success/complete function as :    $('#todolist12').DataTable().fnDraw();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the cell using the dataTables [data()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/cells().data()) method.

For example, you might want the success function to look something like this:

```
success: function() { 
    $('#todolist12').DataTable().cells("#idOfChangedCell").data("Update to cell").
}
```

For the change to actually appear on your webpage, however, you also need to invoke the dataTables draw() method:

```
$('#todolist12').DataTable().draw();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! My datatable is created dynamically with entries from my database. So what should I enter instead of "#idofchangedCell"? Any suggestions?

Comment: That's kind of out of my hands, that was just to show you the structure of how the statement works. I don't know how your table is built to know what selector you need for finding the changed cell.

Answer (score 0):

you could do a location.reload() to reload the page.

If you don't want to reload the page, then you need to make your table loadable over ajax.  To be really slick, you would be able to load a single row.

You could also return the new row as the response from your save request and just update the table with the new markup.

Or you could use javascript templates to render the data on the client and return the record as json.

You have a lot of options, but it's up to you as the dev to determine the right solution.  There isn't a single line or several lines that will solve your issue other than location.reload().  It all depends on how  your app is written now, or how you modify it to do what you want it to do.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but to be honest that does not help me a lot! I know that there are many options but as I said I want to reload ONLY my table once the changes are done in the database. So I am looking for a solution or a function for the "success" part of my ajax code!